# Add an aws_security_group_rule that contains self and a security group id to a security group

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I'm trying to add a security group rule that allows from port 9200 to 9200, but I need to specify the security groups, and I also need to add self to that specific rule.

I have tried it both ways:

```
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "port_9200_por_for_nexgen_search_es" {
    description       = "9200 self port for nexgen search es"
    type              = "ingress"
    from_port         = 9200
    to_port           = 9200
    protocol          = "9200"
    source_security_group_id = aws_security_group.nexgen_log.id
    self              = true
    security_group_id = aws_security_group.nexgen_search_es_sg_GrayLog.id
}
```

and

```
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "port_9200_por_for_nexgen_search_es" {
    description       = "9200 self port for nexgen search es"
    type              = "ingress"
    from_port         = 9200
    to_port           = 9200
    protocol          = "9200"
    self              = true
    security_group_id = aws_security_group.nexgen_search_es_sg_GrayLog.id
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "port_9200_por_for_nexgen_search_es" {
    description       = "9200  port for nexgen search es"
    type              = "ingress"
    from_port         = 9200
    to_port           = 9200
    protocol          = "9200"
    source_security_group_id = aws_security_group.nexgen_log.id
    security_group_id = aws_security_group.nexgen_search_es_sg_GrayLog.id
}
```

but they both give me errors, the first one gives me: `Error: "source_security_group_id": conflicts with self`

The second says that the rule is already created.

Is there any way to handle this differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two resources can not share the same type and name. I'd guess Terraform is misinterpreting the attributes of both definitions as a single resource and trying to make it work.

```
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "port_9200_por_for_nexgen_search_es_1" {
...
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "port_9200_por_for_nexgen_search_es_2" {
...
}
```

Comment: ive been coding for a while and i completly missed that one, thank you very much